# Validacion de numeros y letras sin que intefieran JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta peque validación que se ejecuta con un blur en los input... La regla de negocio de esta es que si la calificación que ponen es menor a 5 o mayor 10 mande una alerta que ya tengo, eso funciona ya de lujo, ahora necesito agregar una mas aparte de esa , que es la siguiente:

**Si el valor que ponen en el input es diferente a "NP", "SD", "NA" también mande el error, pero respetando la primera regla de negocio.**

Como puedo hacer para que se cumplan las dos reglas de negocio sin que en la segunda regla de negocio interfiera con la primera, xq si pongo ejemplo:

Calificación = 9.6 esto es valido para la primera regla de negocio, pero para la segunda regla ya no es valido porque 9.6 no es un valor "NP", "SD", "NA"...

***¿¿COMO FORMULAR DE FORMA CORRECTA EL IF para que funcionen las dos reglas de negocio??***

Gracias!

```
$(".calificacion").on({
    blur: function(e) {
        formatCurrency($(this));
    },
});


function formatCurrency(input) {

    var input_val = input.val();
    var letrasPermitidas = ["NP", "SD", "NA"];


    if ((input_val > 10 || input_val < 0.99) || (input_val > 0.99 && input_val < 5)) {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Oops...',
            text: 'No puedes asignar calificaciones menores a 5 o mayores a 10',
        })
        input.val("");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo ***Calificación*** puede ser

- Un valor *numerico*
- cualquiera de estos tres *NP*, *SD*, *NA*
- No se pueden combinar

Si esto es así, podrías hacer una validación inicial con una expresión regular si calificación es un numero o una cadena de caracteres.
Para eso puedes usar el metodo `test()`.

### /regex/.test()

> El método `test()` ejecuta la búsqueda de una ocurrencia entre una expresión regular y una cadena especificada. Devuelve true o false.
> [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Para implementarlo tienes cuentas con varias opciones para declarar las expresiones regulares y [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) puedes encontrar más información al respecto.
En este caso yo voy a crear de manera literal la expresión e inmediatamente a usar el método `test()`, validando si la `calificacion` es un numero de la siguiente manera

```
/^[0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]+$/.test(cadena)
```

Donde

- `/^[0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]+$/` es la expresión regular.
- `cadena` es la cadena a comparar contra la expresión regular

Como el método `test()` te devuelve un *true* o *false* lo podemos poner directamente en `if`

```js
$(".calificacion").on({
    blur: function(e) {
        formatCurrency($(this));
    },
});


function formatCurrency(input) {

    var input_val = input.val();
    var letrasPermitidas = ["NP", "SD", "NA"];


    if(/^[0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]+$/.test(input_val)){
        if ((input_val > 10 || input_val < 0.99) || (input_val > 0.99 && input_val < 5)) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'No puedes asignar calificaciones menores a 5 o mayores a 10',
            })
            input.val("");
        }
    }else{
        /* Aquí verificas si la calificación es (NA || NP || SD) */
    }
}
```

---

### Más detalle sobre la expresión regular /^[0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]+$/

Primero señalar que para declarar una expresión regular puedes hacerlo iniciando una cadena de texto con `/` y terminarla con otro `/` y todo lo que quede dentro será la expresión regular.
Por ejemplo, si quieres encontrar ***"Hola"*** dentro de una cadena, declaras la expresión como `/Hola/`. Y esto nos dice que busque una letra *H* seguida de una *o*, seguida de una *l* y que finalize con una *a*.
La otra opción es declarar un patrón como es el caso de `/^[0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]+$/`

- Los corchetes `[]` son para indicar que se busque cualquiera de los elementos que hay dentro de ellos. Por ejemplo `[abc]` buscará cualquier coincidencia de `a`, de `b`, o de `c`. También se puede pedir un rango de elementos como por ejemplo, números del 0 al 9, y si, esa es precisamente la primer parte de la expresión regular. `[0-9` buscará coincidencias de números del 0 al 9.
- El `+` nos indica que debe de haber por lo menos un elemento del anterior señalado. Por ejemplo `a+` tendrá coincidencia con cadenas de **a**, **aa**, ***aaa***, etc.
- El `\` se utiliza para escapar caracteres especiales como lo es `.` que por si solo en las expresiones regulares significa **cualquier carácter**
- `{0,1}` nos indica que el elemento anterior puede estar de creo a una vez.
- `^` y `$` son "anclas" que nos indican como debe terminar e iniciar una cadena. `^` es el que dice como debe iniciar una cadena y va al inicio del carácter, por ejemplo, `^[0-9]` nos dice que debe iniciar un numero. Y `[0-9]$` nos dice que debe terminar con un numero

De esta forma `/^[0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]+$/` nos dice que la cadena

- `^[0-9]+` debe iniciar con un numero y puede haber mas de uno.
- `\.{0,1}` puede haber o no un punto.
- `[0-9]+$` debe de finalizar con uno o más números.

9
9.0
12323412
21342134213.12342341234
0.6583568